# Least squares fit routine for timescaling in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, scaling, least-squares

I would like to know if there is a least squares routine in Matlab to scale a template signal to a measured signal in time. Let's say my template is a signal of approx. 1 second, but the corresponding part in the measurement is 1.2 seconds. Now I want to scale my template to be 1.2 seconds long as well. Of course it is possible to simply rescale the template in several steps, cross-correlate with the signal for each step and find the maximum. This however would slow down my programme drastically.
Matlab's lsqcurvefit needs two vectors of equal length, and the length of one of the vectors is exactly what I want to vary.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand where the optimization comes into it. If you have the length of the template and the desired length, what else can you change other than to just stretch or compress it (and perhaps do some interpolation)?

Comment: Can't you just multiply your template time vector by 1.2? I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Do you want to "stretch" the signal, or do you want to extrapolate?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the corresponding length of the signal. The template is the acceleration signal of one step in a normalized gait pattern. I want to cross correlate several templates (i.e. for normal gait, stair climbing and descending) with an acceleration signal containing many steps. However, the steps in this signal can be longer or shorter (in duration) than the template. So I want to fit my template (stretch/compress) to the step(s) in the measurement signal, and do this for each 'lag' of the cross correlation.
Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: @mlipperts: you can use Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) technique http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried the simple `fminsearch` function approach? It might not be as slow as you think.

e.g. (untested - just for illustration)

```
x=template; y=data;
fn=@(p)sum(( x(:)-y( 1+max(0,min(length(y),floor([0:(length(x)-1)]-p(1)).*p(2))) ) ).^2)
b=fminsearch(fn,[0 1]); % [offset, scale]
```

you'll probably need to tweak the limits etc!

It it doesn't suit, you could also look at the CPM toolbox (though it may be too sophisticated for your needs)
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jenn/alignmentStudy/